# Network profile paging design problem

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, network-profile

Steps to reproduce:

1. Visit the network profile (global StackExchange profile) of someone e.g. [Jon Skeet](https://stackexchange.com/users/a1c71168-ffb9-42a5-8d71-ce38ad8f2c79)
2. On any tab that contains paging you will notice such thing:
   [image]

The paging works, but "hidden" behind the footer background - think it needs to be on top of the footer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some sticky-footer-css fixes we pushed yesterday caused this (in Chrome, at least), but adding `clear:both` fixed the issue. Thanks for the report.